# JS подcчёт строк

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

Добрый день.

Есть в цикл:

```
$.getJSON('_json.php?email=' + orgData.email, function(verifyData) {                            
setServerStatus('Item:'+ index + ' ok');

$('#office').append('<br>' + orgData.title + ';' + orgData.director + ';' + 
                                                                orgData.email  + ';' + orgData.webSiteUrl  + ';' + data5.country  + ';'+ virifyData.status +'');

index++;
});
```

Нужно каждые 100 строк выполнять запрос.

К примеру:

```
$.getJSON('_json2.php?email2=' + orgData.email, function(verifyData2) { }
```

Т.е. выполняется в цикле тот код и, спустя каждые 100 строк, выполняется либо запрос, либо функция вызова запроса.

Сейчас у меня просто считаются строки от 0 до бесконечности.

Нужно, чтобы когда счетчик дошел до 100, вызвалась функция и счетчик либо сбросился снова до 0, либо    продолжил подсчет, но через 100, снова запустилась функция.

Помогите пожалуйста, я - новичок.

Comment: virify на verify исправьте, комментарий по грамматике

Answer (score 1):

Взятия числа по модулю `%` даёт 0 когда `index` кратен 100 => `index%100 == 0`

```
$.getJSON('_json.php?email=' + orgData.email, function(verifyData) {                            
setServerStatus('Item:'+ index + ' ok');

$('#office').append('<br>' + orgData.title + ';' + orgData.director + ';' + 
                                                                orgData.email  + ';' + orgData.webSiteUrl  + ';' + data5.country  + ';'+ virifyData.status +'');

  if(index%100 == 0)
     $.getJSON('_json2.php?email2=' + orgData.email, function(verifyData2) { }   
  index++;
});
```